# Is the verb 'get' really a causative verb?

Tags: causatives, causative-get

There's an explanation that the causative get means convincing 'someone else' to do something, and I know there's the case as "I got my hair cut", but lately I've been seeing the opposite cases a lot, such as...

1. "Let's get this done together"
2. "The authority was the one that got it approved"

Those kind of sentences have the same structures as in the causative get's cases, "get something PP", but imply that the speaker or the subject, not someone else, are the ones who do the actual stuff. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the first one is a different idiom, _get it done_ meaning "complete it", with an implication that it is difficult or arduous. I don't recognise the second example.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks, how about this one? "You are the one who got it approved": Here, 'you' is a someone in charge, and 'it' is a form of document stamped by 'you'.

Comment: No, to me "You are the one who got it approved" implies that you got somebody else to approve it.

Comment: For your second example, what I would take it to mean is that the authority got somebody else (it's not clear who) to approve it.